# How can I execute a command with a motion to the next/previous number?

Tags: cursor-motions

I want to essentially be able to use a command similar to `dt#`, where the `#` represents any numerical character.

My use case is modifying a script where I have a few server instances with long names that I wanted to abbreviate, from:

```
instance0
instance1
instance2
instance3
```

to

```
i0
i1
i2
i3
```

Is that possible without a regex? It would be useful to have something similar that includes a way to represent any alpha or symbol too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing your cursor on the second character in your string (`n`), you could use `d/\d`.

I suppose this does count as regex still, but looking at the documentation of `t` and `f`, they both use `{char}` which does not seem to include character groups or types such as `\d` represents digits in a regex pattern.

```
i[n]stance0
instance1
instance2
instance3
```

`d/\d`

```
i0
instance1
instance2
instance3
```

Comment: This looks pretty much what I was thinking of! So `d/\d` uses a forward search to the next digit character as the motion? http://vimregex.com/#metacharacters

Comment: Yup, that is correct!

Comment: Then you can use j.j.j.